# How much of a screen to overlay for popups?

Tags: popup, overlay

[image]I'm currently designing a dashboard (with a left navigation menu).

When users are performing a task for example, to subscribe to a certain provider, there will be a pop-up modal to let them know what's happening and to confirm their actions. The pop-up will have a black overlay behind it.

The question is, should the black overlay cover the left-side navigation menu as well (so that it cover the entire web browser) or should it just be within the content itself - this means that users can get away from the pop-up by clicking on another menu link.

Comment: Allowing user to get away pop up by clicking on some other menu is not recommended. Either user should select action inside popup or close popup to return back to screen.

Comment: Hi Omkar, thank you for the suggestion. That makes sense too!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use a fullscreen lightbox/ overlay. Otherwise there's to much options for the User. Think about what the User is confronted with when he doesnt use the CTA but uses the Left-Navigation? Could be confusing.....

My suggestion is to make it clear and use a fullscreen overlay.

Comment: Hello! They have to trigger some kind of CTA for it to disappear. They can either click on "Cancel" or "Proceed".

Comment: Okay, so the suggestion is to overlay the left navigation menu as well, and to also centralise the pop-up to the middle of the screen?